# AngularJS: Two way binding video's currentTime with directive

Tags: angularjs, html5-video

I have being trying to figuring out a simple directive pattern for controlling html5 video/youtube video.

I wanted to do it the "Angular way", thus bind video's property to a object model. However I have some problem when dealing with "currentTime" property of a video, since it's constantly updating.

Here is what I got so far:

html control:

```
<!--range input that both show and control $scope.currentTime -->
<input type="range" min=0 max=60  ng-model="currentTime">

<!--bind main $scope.currentTime to someVideo directive's videoCurrentTime -->
<video some-video video-current-time="currentTime"> </video>
```

directive:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentTime = 0;
})

app.directive('someVideo', function ($window) {
    return{
        scope: {
            videoCurrentTime: "=videoCurrentTime"
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {

            $scope.onTimeUpdate = function () {
                $scope.videoCurrentTime = $element[0].currentTime;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, elm) {
            scope.$watch('videoCurrentTime', function (newVar) {
                elm[0].currentTime = newVar;

            });
            elm.bind('timeupdate', scope.onTimeUpdate);
        }
    }

})
```

JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5wQ/

::

While this seems works, notice that everytime `onTimeUpdate` fires, it triggers the `$watch`.

For example, when the video runs to 10 secs, it notify onTimeUpdate to change the model to 10, and $watch will catch this change and ask the video to seek to 10 sec **again**.

This sometime **creates a loop** that causes video to lag from times to times.

Do you think there is a better way to do this? A way that won't trigger unwanted $watch ? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What's the resolution on 'currentTime'? I know that `ontimeupdate` runs approximately once every frame of video (many times a second) - does `currentTime` get sub-second precision? IF so, inside the `$watch` you could check for a minimum difference between `newVar` and `elem[0].currentTime` before making the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excerpt from some [timeupdate documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441309.aspx) says that the function bound to timeupdate is invoked when you

> - Play the video
> - Move the position indicator on the playback controls

So the event gets fired when the playback gets modified, and you don't need to explicitly $watch the model attached to that playback control.

This means that you can do both your updates in the timeupdate listener, instead of having the external-model-to-video assignment in a watch statement... but make sure you check a threshold like jkjustjoshing mentioned in his comment in order to be sure that the control has actually been moved.

```
$scope.onTimeUpdate = function () {
    var currTime = $element[0].currentTime;
    if (currTime - $scope.videoCurrentTime > 0.5 ||
            $scope.videoCurrentTime - currTime > 0.5) {
        $element[0].currentTime = $scope.videoCurrentTime;
    }
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.videoCurrentTime = $element[0].currentTime;
    });
};
```

Another note:  I'm not sure this is relevant to you, but once the video has ended, it won't play again until you explicitly call `play()` even if you set its `currentTime`.  To get around this you can use a $watch statement on `videoCurrenTime` that restarts the video if it has ended.

Your original code wasn't very laggy, but here's an updated fiddle that seemed to have a couple seconds less lag (from my limited testing at least):
http://jsfiddle.net/B7hT5/

Comment: I think this was what I ended up doing (which was a while ago). I was hoping that everything follows a model, but sometimes it's just not the best way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove lags update watch for videoCurrentTime

```
scope.$watch('videoCurrentTime', function (newVar) {
                if (newVar && (0.1 < newVar - elm[0].currentTime || 0.1 < elm[0].currentTime - newVar)) {
                    elm[0].currentTime = newVar;
                }
            });
```